# CSS - column heading rotation as well as fixed header when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to display a table that needs to have its **column headings rotated**, as well as **stay to the top of the page when the user scrolls down**.
I can kind of get it working, but the issue is the width of the columns. I think there's an issue with my CSS. The scrolling of the header works using a separate JS file.

This is what my page looks like at the moment. I've coloured different elements so I can easily demonstrate the issue.
[image: column heading issue]

The column heading text (the green parts below) is in a div with a class called rotated_text.
The cell (the red parts below) has a class called rotated_cell.

The issue is that I can't seem to get the width of the columns to shrink and fit to the values inside it (the green part), and I can't get the green part to extend all the way up the cell (some of the values are on two "lines" as you can see).

I'd like the output to be something like this (done using an Excel file but it's generally how I'd like it to look):

[image: desired output]

My code is below:

```css
.normalHeadingText {
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

 .rotated_text {
  -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg); 
  -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform-origin:  top left;
   position:relative;
  text-align: left;
  top:20px;
  width:100px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color:#A1D490;
 }

 .rotated_cell {
  height:250px;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
   background-color:#D4A190;
}
  
th, td 
  {
   border: 1px solid #888888;
   /*width: 20px;*/
  }

  


.columnHeadingNormal {
 font-weight: bold;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

.cellNormal {
 border: 1px solid #888888;
}

.cellNameSize {
 width:230px;
}


.reportTable {
 width: 100%;
 border-collapse: separate;
 border-spacing: 0px;

 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Report</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Title</h1>
 <table class='reportTable'>
  <thead>
   <tr class='header'>
    <th class='columnHeadingNormal cellNameSize'>Name</th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Allcorn,
      Mason</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Armstrong,
      Bree</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Barmby,
      Matthew</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Barnett,
      Brydon</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Bartlett,
      Patrick</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Bell,
      Chris</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Benson,
      Oliver</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Bisinella,
      Tiana</div></th>
    
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Bowen,
      Joshua</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Brayshaw,
      James</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Brew,
      Alana</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Brogden,
      Bailey</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Buckley,
      Matthew</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Burns,
      Hayden</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Cain,
      Jack</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Cannard,
      Patrick</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Crapper,
      Josh</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Davison,
      Olivia</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Dean,
      Darryl</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Debeljuh,
      Natalie</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Dickson,
      Eric</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Doolan,
      Briane</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Draper,
      Flynn</div></th>
    
   </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class='cellNormal'>Johnstone, William</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>


    
    
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class='cellNormal'>Johnstone, William</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class='cellNormal'>Johnstone, William</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class='cellNormal'>Johnstone, William</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
   </tr>
   
  </tbody>
 </table>

 <br />
 <br />
 <br />

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong with my CSS/HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the text to `position: absolute;` and remove the `top: 20px;`. I also added `height: 7%;`

```css
.normalHeadingText {
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

 .rotated_text {
  -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg); 
  -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform-origin:  top left;
   position:relative;
  text-align: left;
  width:100px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color:#A1D490;
     position: absolute;
     height: 7%;
 }

 .rotated_cell {
  height:250px;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   background-color:#D4A190;
}
  
th, td 
  {
   border: 1px solid #888888;
   /*width: 20px;*/
  }

  


.columnHeadingNormal {
 font-weight: bold;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

.cellNormal {
 border: 1px solid #888888;
}

.cellNameSize {
 width:230px;
}


.reportTable {
 width: 100%;
 border-collapse: separate;
 border-spacing: 0px;

 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Report</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Title</h1>
 <table class='reportTable'>
  <thead>
   <tr class='header'>
    <th class='columnHeadingNormal cellNameSize'>Name</th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Allcorn,
      Mason</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Armstrong,
      Bree</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Barmby,
      Matthew</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Barnett,
      Brydon</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Bartlett,
      Patrick</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Bell,
      Chris</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Benson,
      Oliver</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Bisinella,
      Tiana</div></th>
    
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Bowen,
      Joshua</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Brayshaw,
      James</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Brew,
      Alana</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Brogden,
      Bailey</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Buckley,
      Matthew</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Burns,
      Hayden</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Cain,
      Jack</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Cannard,
      Patrick</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Crapper,
      Josh</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Davison,
      Olivia</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Dean,
      Darryl</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Debeljuh,
      Natalie</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Dickson,
      Eric</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Doolan,
      Briane</div></th>
    <th class='rotated_cell' colspan='1'><div class='rotated_text'>Draper,
      Flynn</div></th>
    
   </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class='cellNormal'>Johnstone, William</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>


    
    
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class='cellNormal'>Johnstone, William</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class='cellNormal'>Johnstone, William</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class='cellNormal'>Johnstone, William</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
    <td class='cellNormal'>0</td>
   </tr>
   
  </tbody>
 </table>

 <br />
 <br />
 <br />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps. However, the text is still spreading over two lines in the column headers. Is there another setting I need to change?

Comment: Have you tried to view it on full page? It is because your table is shrinking when it's on small screen.

Comment: your `table` has a `width: 100%:`. It will make the table shrink when on small screen that ruins the table's columns. It's not a good idea to make a table responsive. Use `div` to wrap your `table`. Just like the bootstrap did in their responsive `table`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I got this working on my site now. Looks much better!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width to 100% and the height to 100% in the .rotated_text class...